# Intellij 14: configure end of code lines

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, editor

Where can I set up the limit of the end of line? I dont want Intellij automatically cut the code lines, it is annoying when you have all tabulated. I prefer no limit because my notebook has a little display.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck `Use soft wrap in editor` is the solution.
[image]

Comment: I have already unchecked my friend, I dont get it. I have noticed that my problem happens in html files, java and groovy files are OK.

Comment: Let's attach screenshot inside your question and try to description about your problem. I will come back.